What do Germans call a casual conversation?
I've been living here for almost 7 years and I don't think I've ever heard Germans mention the concept of a casual conversation or chat the way English does.
I never heard classmates or coworkers use "Unterhaltung", and I associate "Gespräch" with a more formal or work environment.
"Unterhaltung" definitely occurs though more as a verb, and I've seen it used when referring to, for example, dates, or two friends catching up after a long time apart.
I want to mention to a friend that, "... and I remembered the conversation we had at the cafeteria" and I don't know how to express an idea similar to that in German.
If it helps, I live in northern Germany.

The verb is quatschen or klatschen, and the noun is der Klatsch — gossip. (But mind you: der Quatsch — bollocks.)
For your example, die Unterhaltung would fit much better though. Or you stick to the verbs:

… und ich hab daran gedacht, dass wir in der Cafeteria gequatscht haben.

There's also a verb bequatschen that is for quatschen with a set goal. It fits even better in your context:

… und ich hab daran gedacht, was wir in der Cafeteria bequatscht haben.


For me, the verb plaudern most closely resembles the english verb chat.
In Austrian german (and probably Bavarian german) there is also tratschen, which literally translated is to gossip, but which is also used in the sense of just having a chat with a friend.
Whether plaudern or quatschen (as suggested by the other answer) is preferred probably differs regionally.

To contribute two substantives:

Schwatz (DWDS classifies it as colloquial)
Schnack (regionally limited, used in north, north-west of Germany)


Both Unterhaltung and Gepräch are quite common and fit the bill.
Gespräch is neutral in tone and encompasses the whole range of verbal exchange from formal (Vorstellungsgespräch, Personalgespräch) to informal (Pausengespräch, Stadtgespräch), while Unterhaltung leans more towards the friendly and informal, influenced by its second meaning entertainment.

A Plausch or, more casually, a Pläuschchen.
